How to make a link preview blot in Quill editor on link paste?
When user pastes a link into editor, the link should be converted to preview (title, image, description, etc.)
First created a PreviewBlot
const REGEXP_URL = /https?:\/\/[^\s]+/g;

export class PreviewBlot extends Link {
  static blotName = 'preview';
  static className = 'ql-preview';
  static tagName = 'div';

  static create(value: string): HTMLElement {
    console.log('should create preview');  // not called on 2nd approach
    const node = super.create(value);
    // Fetch metadata and append to node
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/opengraph?url=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(metadata => {
        const preview = document.createElement('div');
        preview.innerHTML = `
          <img src="${metadata.image}" alt="${metadata.title}" />
          <h3>${metadata.title}</h3>
          <p>${metadata.description}</p>
        `;
        node.appendChild(preview);
      });
    return node;
  }
}

Next you need to intercept that user pastes a link:
quill.clipboard.addMatcher(Node.TEXT_NODE, (node, delta) => {
    if (node.nodeName !== '#text') {
      return delta;
    }
    const textNode = node as Text;
    const matches = textNode.data.match(REGEXP_URL);
    if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
      console.log('USING MATCHER');
      const ops = [];
      let str = textNode.data;
      matches.forEach(match => {
        const split = str.split(match);
        const beforeLink = split.shift();
        ops.push({insert: beforeLink});
        console.log('should push preview');
        ops.push({insert: match, attributes: {preview: match}});
        str = split.join(match);
      });
      ops.push({insert: str});
      delta.ops = ops;
    }
    return delta;
  });

The matcher is called when you cut text from editor and paste in back.
The matcher is not called when you copy a link from browser's address bar and paste the link into editor.
I consider this may be a bug in Quill.
So I tried 2nd approach:
quill.on('text-change', delta => {
    const ops = delta.ops;
    const insert = ops?.[ops.length - 1]?.insert;
    const matches = typeof insert === 'string' && insert.match(REGEXP_URL);
    if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
      console.log('USING EVENT');
      const ops = [];
      let str = insert;
      for (const match of matches) {
        const split = str.split(match);
        const beforeLink = split.shift();
        ops.push({insert: beforeLink});
        ops.push({insert: match, attributes: {preview: match}});
        str = split.join(match);
      }
      ops.push({insert: str});
      delta.ops = ops;
    }
  });

But this time the PreviewBlot is not inserted despite we change ops in delta to create the preview.
Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ctmwke?file=src%2Findex.html
Case 1: copy a link from browser's address bar and paste into editor - doesn't work
Case 2: cut link from editor and paste it back - the proper PrewiewBolt is inserted
